# Strange redirects on sonarqube

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, sonarqube, kubernetes-ingress, traefik

We have a reverse proxy (traefik) that handles our redirects for sonarqube. It seems like all of our requests going to the api returns a 302

[image]

It always returns `/api` as the new location. Locally everything seems to work as expected:

[image]

This is our ingress rule:

[image]

We're using Gitlab as our SAML -- does anyone have a clue why this may be happening?

Comment: Would you share your Traefik configuration?

Comment: @syn Not sure if you meant the configuration or just ingress. I added the ingress image to the description, but I can also add what our traefik config tomorrow morning.